# How to get & parse the values of ITune's EQ presets

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, audio, audio-processing

We are trying to implement a music player app with Equalizer presets. We are successful in getting presets from iPod and applying it through audio unit. But, now we need to display sliders and set frequency with respect to the selected preset. But we are not aware of the values which need to be set to sliders for a particular frequency.

We need to achieve this kind of UI. The slider need to update with preset value change.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So your question is how to create an equalizer for iOS?

Comment: _"We are successful in getting presets from iPod"_ you have a file? Does it list 10 values (each ranging from -12 to +12)? Those 10 will be your preset values (usually going from left to right, ie: 32hz up to 16k.hz). If unsure why not make your own preset with known values and export it then check the bytes (via hex editor) to see which bytes you read fro which known number...